# Confusion with layout of string variables in storage

Tags: solidity, documentation

From solidity docs, in section [Layout of State Variables in Storage > bytes and strings](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.21/internals/layout_in_storage.html#bytes-and-string)

There is this explanation (v: v0.8.21):

> In particular: if the data is at most 31 bytes long, the elements are stored in the higher-order bytes (left aligned) and the lowest-order byte stores the value length * 2. For byte arrays that store data which is 32 or more bytes long, the main slot p stores length * 2 + 1 and the data is stored as usual in keccak256(p). This means that you can distinguish a short array from a long array by checking if the lowest bit is set: short (not set) and long (set).

The way I understand it, in both cases, short or long there would be something at the lowest order bit location.

In short string case, last bytes would have `length * 2`.

For example, string `hello` would look like `0x68656c6c6f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a` and `hello there` would look like `0x68656c6c6f207468657265000000000000000000000000000000000000000016`. These are both under 32 characters and have their length times 2 in lowest significant bits as expected.

In long string case, least order bits (and the only item in that storage location) would have `length * 2 + 1`.

For example, `hello therehello therehello therehello therehello therehello therehello there` would look like `0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000009b`
Again, the lowest order bits would contain the length information, this time `length * 2 + 1`.

My confusion is with the last sentence from above docs:

> This means that you can distinguish a short array from a long array by checking if the lowest bit is set: short (not set) and long (set).

Is this a remnant from an older version of solidity where short strings did not have their length information as part of the storage slot? By just looking at the least significant bits (as that sentence implies), how can we tell if something is a short version string or a long version string? Am I missing something here or do docs just need to be updated here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the low bytes have a value of less than 32, then the string is short, and the text is located in the higher order bytes.

This is likely done to save space, similar to packing variables less than 32 bytes long.

Comment: True and good observation there but it still does not explain the wording in docs. Specifically, the last sentence. Lowest bit IS still set, regardless of if it's a short or long string.

Comment: That's right - that's the bit
Any string length multiplied by two gives a number where the least significant bit == 0.
So for a long string, the formula: length * 2 + 1 will always set the low-order bit == 1.
You can check the bit in different ways. For example 

value % 2 == 1 ? 
or 
value & 1 == 1 ?

Comment: Ahhh right, thank you Alexey! I knew there was something simple I was missing there.